# Installing OpenCV and use face recognizer on Matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv

I am trying to use opencv in Matlab. I already applied all the recommended methods on internet. The opencv is already installed and can be used in MATLAB. 
The problem is when I want to use LBPHFaceREcognizer or BasicFaceRecognizer functions, I got an error. The error is :

```
Undefined function or variable 'LBPHFaceRecognizer_'.

Error in cv.LBPHFaceRecognizer (line 129)
        this.id = LBPHFaceRecognizer_(0, 'new', varargin{:});
```

As I searched a lot, this functions are in "opencv_contrib" and has to be added externally to opencv installation. I somehow confused how to connect these libraries and files to MATLAB. (The related file for these functions are called aruco).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Compile OpenCV with contrib modules and Matlab bindings. (Btw, aruco is not related to the FaceRocognizer, it's for aruco markers (QR codes) detection)

Comment: @Miki Thanks for your answer. But how to do that?? (Compile OpenCV with contrib modules and Matlab bindings)

Comment: @Miki I tried again and I found this error in the Cmake compiling 

Matlab:
mex: C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/mex.bat
Compiler/generator: Not working (bindings will not be generated)

Dont know why!!!!!